# Why there is no link in "peer reviewed" while editing tag wiki?

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

After editing a question I usually see like this:

[image]

In this case, there is a link linked to the text **peer reviewed** where I can click and see the review status of my edit.

But in case of tag wiki edit, It showed the following:

[image]

where there is no link linked to the text **peer reviewed**.

Why? I think it also should be like the first one.

Note that, I know that I can see it by going to my profile's Activity > all actions > suggestion, but it is a little bit painful!

Comment: This isn't a bug... [Given how rare tag wiki edits are compared to edits on questions and answers, it's not a priority at the moment. We may come back to it eventually, but it probably won't be soon.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172828/can-thanks-for-your-edit-banner-be-linkified-with-the-suggested-edit-link#comment787494_240375) (from [Laura](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/166017/laura), a PM for Stack Exchange)

Comment: Cross-site [feature-request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255841/link-to-review-entry-in-header-after-suggesting-a-tag-wiki-edit) with suggested implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one is implemented a few months ago and it covers a huge number of people comparing to the second one. As tag wiki edits are rare, **the authority has no plan to implement it for tag edit in near future**.

Source:

[This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172828/can-thanks-for-your-edit-banner-be-linkified-with-the-suggested-edit-link#comment787494_240375) source is provided by @hichris123. Thanks to him for informing.